# spring boot custom configurations

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to setup the elastic search custom connection parameters in some application.properties file. 
like

```
myelastic.server = 192.168.1.1
myelastic.port = 11111
```

I need to load this values on application startup and create the transport client component for elastic search 5.4

How can I load this values on startup to the model/properties. ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below code in your model class:

```
 @Value("${myelastic.server}") 
 String server;

 @Value("${myelastic.port}") 
 int port;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access properties either using @Value annotation or Autowiring Environment from spring.

Get the properties values using @Value:

```
@Value("${myelastic.server}")
private String elasticServer;

@Value("${myelastic.port}")
private int elasticPort;

@Value("${elasticsearch.clustername}")
private String EsClusterName;
```

and create Transport client as below:

```
 @Bean
public Client client() throws Exception {

    Settings esSettings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
            .put("cluster.name", EsClusterName)
            .build();

    return TransportClient.builder()
            .settings(esSettings)
            .build()
            .addTransportAddress(
              new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(elasticServer), elasticPort));
}
```